# OpenVPN - Client traffic is not entirely routed through VPN

Tags: vpn, iptables, openvpn, gateway, route

I installed OpenVPN on my dedicated server.
Using Viscosity or Tunnelblick on the client, I successfully connected to this server.

However, after some tests, I realized that not all the traffic generated by the client goes through the server. Rather than using 1000 words to explain it, I made an image :

*Image is clickable*
[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the yellow part on the server side doesn't show any activity. I get the same phenomenon for YouTube videos loading for example.

Here is my OpenVPN server configuration file :

```
mode server
proto tcp
port 1199
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh1024.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

keepalive 10 120
client-to-client
user nobody
group nogroup
chroot /etc/openvpn/jail
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
verb 3
mute 20
status openvpn-status.log
```

And here is the client .opvn configuration file :

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote MY.SER.VER.IP 1199
resolv-retry infinite
cipher AES-256-CBC
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Any idea what's wrong ?

**EDIT:**

I also tried to create the following iptables rule (found on [openvpn.net How To page](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect)):
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

It doesn't change my problem. However, I can't see any new rule when using `iptables --list`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: can you provide a paste of the routing table of the OpenVPN client before and after connecting. If not, what OS is the client running?

Comment: The client is running Mac OS 10.8.3. How do I get the routing table of Mac OS ?

Comment: run the command `netstat -nr`

Comment: Here you go. Before connection: http://pastebin.com/kVL84dX5. After connection: http://pastebin.com/9bCSUrN0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Mike's answer gave me the clue. Viscosity does override some settings.

The solution is to add the redirect command in *Extra OpenVPN configuration commands*.
To do so, *Edit* your connection, go to *Advanced* tab, and add `push "redirect-gateway def1"`:
[image: redirect gateway def1 rule in Viscosity]

And as Mike said, don't forget to check *Send all traffic over vpn connection* in Networking tab:
[image: Send all traffic over vpn connection in Viscosity]

Answer (score 2):

using Viscosity.. just overwrite the routes getting pushed by the vpn server.. Edit the config of the connection -> networking -> send all traffic over vpn connection

Comment: I already tried to check this box. The problem remains the same. However, I didn't neither fill the "Default Gateway" nor add a rule. Should I ?

Answer (score 0):

To see your nat traffic with iptables use iptables -L -x -n -v -t nat

It will produce an output like so:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 18025 packets, 1535609 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5580 packets, 335412 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1575   125569 SNAT       all  --  *      em1     10.0.0.10            0.0.0.0/0           /* oscarbass@att.net */ to:77.245.64.130
     833    93632 SNAT       all  --  *      em1     10.0.0.6             0.0.0.0/0           /* oscarbass@bassdesigns.net */ to:77.245.64.130
    6585   477765 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      em1     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 12118 packets, 810032 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```